# Search a text In Jquery AutoComplete Ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have a autocomplete ui in which there is a pre defined User list as source.
When a user selects a user from the list, it's id is saved in a hidden field. Up to here it is fine. Now, If the user writes a user name that is not in the autocomplete list then I need to change the value of hidden field to 0 and do other tasks. But i am not able to do this...

I tried using the .change event, but its not working. 
Here is the code.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CHService.asmx/GetClient",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#txtName').autocomplete({
                        minLength: 0,
                        source: function (req, responseFn) {
                            var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                            var a = $.grep(data.d, function (item, index) {
                                return matcher.test(item.value);
                            });
                            responseFn(a);
                        }, //Searches user input with first letter of ...//data.d
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                            $('#txtName').val(ui.item.value);
                            $('#HFuser').val(ui.item.Name);

                            alert('Select' + ui.item.Name);
                            //return false;
                        },
                        change: function (event, ui) {
                            alert('Change' + ui.item.Name);
                            if (ui.item == null) {
                                $('#HFuser').val(0);


                                //return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

So, How Basically I need is to, Set `UserId` when user selects the value from autocomplete, or set `userid=0` when user inputs new value.

```
UPDATE
```

Forgot to add, the .change event doesn't work because, every time the value of `ui.item==null is true` and the alert gave exception due to it.

Comment: till now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299839/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-hybrid-text-id-search is the only thing i came close to (see first answer). but thats another way around.

Comment: is that a valid property there?  ui.item.Name? autosuggest only contains ui.item.label and ui.item.value by default.  are you not getting an error in console?

Comment: No no erros on that. the .Name is defined on my json list so i use it.
Anyway i figured out my problem. Check my answer below, if any suggestions or error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess what, Little bit of tweaking, and I did it myself with some help from friend.

here is the code. It is on the `.change` event.

```
                        var found = false;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                            if ($("#txtName").val() == data.d[i].value) {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (found == false) {
                            $('#HFUserID').val(0);


                        }
```

I did was searched through my `data` one by one, and when not found cleared the User id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the hidden input if autosuggest can not find the current input string in your defined User list, you may want to use the autosuggest.close method.  The suggestion menu will close if there are no matches for the input string.  Here is more information about the "close" method:

> **close( event, ui )Type: autocompleteclose**

Triggered when the menu is hidden. Not every close event will be accompanied by a change event.
event
Type: Event
ui
Type: Object

**Code examples:**

*Initialize the autocomplete with the close callback specified:*
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    close: function( event, ui ) {}
});

*Bind an event listener to the autocompleteclose event*:

$( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteclose", function( event, ui ) {} );

source: [enter link description here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search)

so change this:

```
 change: function (event, ui) {
                        alert('Change' + ui.item.Name);
                        if (ui.item == null) {
                            $('#HFuser').val(0);


                            //return false;
                        }
                    }
```

To:

```
 close: function (event, ui) {
       $('#HFuser').val(0)
  }
```